Why is not possible to download final - image3.png?
This is code where user select one image.
This image is succesfully overlayed by second image and the result is image3.png. But image3 is not possible to download by button. I am not also able to download image by mouse click.
There is not "image3.png" in inspect.
Do you see any error why?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>New image</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="backgroundImageInput" accept="image/*">
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="downloadBtn" style="display: none;">Stáhnout image3</button>

<script>
    
    function drawOverlayedImage(backgroundImage, overlayImage) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        canvas.width = backgroundImage.width;
        canvas.height = backgroundImage.height;
        
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
        ctx.drawImage(overlayImage, 0, 0);
        
        document.getElementById('downloadBtn').style.display = 'block';
    }
    
    
    function downloadImage() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = finalimage;
        link.href = image;
        link.click();
    }
    
    
    document.getElementById('backgroundImageInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        const backgroundImageFile = event.target.files[0];
        if (backgroundImageFile) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                const backgroundImage = new Image();
                backgroundImage.src = e.target.result;
                
                const overlayImage = new Image();
                overlayImage.src = 'image2.png';
                
                overlayImage.onload = function() {
                    const finalimage = drawOverlayedImage(backgroundImage, overlayImage);
                };
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(backgroundImageFile);
        }
    });
    
    
    document.getElementById('downloadBtn').addEventListener('click', downloadImage);
</script>

</body>
</html>



finalimage is undefined in downloadImage and finalimage is scoped only to the listener of overlayImage.onload and when declared is assigned undefined by the return of function drawOverlayedImage. First line of the script add the line "use strict"; to find all the errors your code has.

Failure is coming from downloadImage function where's finalImage variable is not defined.
Anyway, download attribute of an anchor expects a string or no value.
You can fix your code this way :
function downloadImage() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    // Correct here
    link.download = 'image3.png';        
    link.href = image;
    link.click();
}

See this fiddle for demonstration.
